# Comparing TreeMap contents gives incorrect answer

Tags: java, dictionary, hashcode, treemap, compareto

I use a TreeMap as a 'key' inside another TreeMap

ie

```
TreeMap<TreeMap<String, String>, Object>
```

In my code 'object' is a personal construct, but for this intance I have used a string.

I have created a pair of TreeMaps to test the `TreeMap.CompareTo()` and `TreeMap.HashCode()` methods. this starts with the following...

```
public class TreeMapTest 

public void testTreeMap()
{
TreeMap<String, String> first = new TreeMap<String, String>();
TreeMap<String, String> second = new TreeMap<String, String>();

first.put("one", "une");
first.put("two", "deux");
first.put("three", "trois");
second.put("une", "one");
second.put("deux", "two");
second.put("trois", "three");

TreeMap<TreeMap<String, String>, String> english = new TreeMap<TreeMap<String, String>, String>();
TreeMap<TreeMap<String, String>, String> french = new TreeMap<TreeMap<String, String>, String>();

english.put(first, "english");
french.put(second, "french");
```

From here I now call the  the english item to see if it contains the key

```
if (english.containsKey(second))
{
System.out.println("english contains the key");
//throws error of ClassCastException: Java.util.TreeMap cannot be cast to
//Java.Lang.Comparable, reading the docs suggests this is the feature if the key is
//not of a supported type.
//this error does not occur if I use a HashMap structure for all maps, why is
//this key type supported for one map structure but not another?
}
```

However I should note that both HashMap and TreeMap point to the same HashCode() method in the AbstractMap parent.

My first thought was to convert my TreeMap to a HashMap, but this seemed a bit soppy! So I decided to apply the hashCode() method to the 2 treemap objects.

```
int hc1 = first.hashCode();
int hc2 = second.hashCode();



if(hc1 == hc2)
{
systom.out.printline("values are equal " + hc1 + " " + hc2);
}
```

prints the following

```
values are equal 3877431 & 3877431
```

For me the hashcode should be different as the key values are different, I can't find details on the implementation difference of the hashCode() method between HashMap and TreeMap.

Please not the following.
changing the Keys only to HashMap  doesn't stop the ClassCastException error. Changing all the maps to a HashMap does. so there is something  with the containsKey() method in TreeMap that isn't working properly, or I have missunderstood - can anyone explain what?

The section where I get the hashCode of the first and second map objects always produces the same output (no matter if I use a Hash or Tree map here) However the if(english.ContainsKey(second)) doesn't print any message when HashMaps are used, so there is obviously something in the HashMap implementation that is different for the compareTo() method.

My principle questions are.

Where can I find details of the types of keys for use in TreeMap objects (to prevent future 'ClassCastException' errors).

If I can't use a certain type of object as a key, why am I allowed to insert it as a key into the TreeMap in the first place? (surely if I can insert it I should be able to check if the key exists?)

Can anyone suggest another construct that has ordered inster / retrieval to replace my TreeMap key objects?

Or have I potentially found strange behaviour. From my understanding I should be able to do a drop in replacement of TreeMap for HashMap, or have I stumbled upon a fringe scenario?

Thanks in advance for your comments.

David.

ps. the problem isn't a problem in my code as I use a personal utility to create a hash that becomes dependent on the Key and Value pairs (ie I calculate key hash values differently to value hash values... sorry that if is a confusing sentence!) I assume that the hashCode method just sums all the values together without considering if a item is a key or a value.

pps. I'm not sure if this is a good question or not, any pointers on how to improve it?

Edit.

from the responses people seem to think I'm doing some sort of fancy language dictionary stuff, not a surprise from my example, so sorry for that. I used this as an example as it came easily to my brain, was quick to write and demonstrated my question.

The real problem is as follows.

I'm accessing a legacy DB structure, and it doesn't talk nicely to anything (result sets aren't forward and reverse readable etc). So I grab the data and create objects from them.
The smallest object represents a single row in a table (this is the object that in the above example I have used a string value 'english' or 'french' for.

I have a collection of these rowObjects, each row has an obvious key (this is the TreeMap that points to the related rowObject).

i don't know if that makes things any clearer!

Edit 2.

I feel I need to elaborate a little further as to my choice of originaly using

```
hashMap<HashMap<String,string>, dataObject>
```

for my data structure, then converting to TreeMap to gain an ordered view.

In edit 1 I said that the legacy DB doesn't play nicely (this is an issue with the JDBC.ODBC I suspect, and I'm not about to acquire a JDBC to communicate with the DB). The truth is I apply some modifications to the data as as I create my java 'dataObject'. This means that although the DB may spit out the results in ascending or descending order, I have no way of knowing what order they are inserted into my dataObject. Using a likedHashMap seems like a nice solution (see duffymo's suggestion) but I later need to extract the data in an ordered fashion, not just consecutively (LinkedHashMap only preserves insertion order), and I'm not inclined to mess around with ordering everything and making copies when I need to insert a new item in between 2 others, TreMap would do this for me... but if I create a specific object for the key it will simply contain a TreeMap as a member, and obviously I will then need to supply a compareTo and hashCode method. So why not just extent TreeMap (allthough Duffymo has a point about throwing that solution out)!

Comment: You should read the TreeMap documentation. A TreeMap is not a HashMap. It doesn't use `hashCode()`. Its keys are supposed to be comparable, because the whole point a a TreeMap is to use a tree of comparable objects internally. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

Comment: `TreeMap` keys must either be themselves `Comparable`, or you must provide a `Comparator` that can compare their keys.

Comment: @JBNizet I have read the docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/TreeMap.html (note I'm using java 7 not 6). and it states that hashcode is inherited from abstractMap, just like the hashcode of HashMap

Comment: The TreeMap doesn't call hashCode() on its *keys*. The fact that the hashCode() method of TreeMap is inherited has nothing to do with my comment. Your post keeps talking about hashCode(), but hashCode() is completely irrelevant for TreeMap. TreeMap doesn't care about the hashCode of its keys.

Comment: @JBNizet The doc states that TreMap.put(k,v) Throws: ClassCastException - if the specified key cannot be compared with the keys currently in the map. So if TreeMap doesn't implement both comparable and hashcode somewhere in its inheritence I wouldn't be able to use one as a key without throwing an error (which doesn't happen). That is probably a better description of my question. TreeMap is apparently not comparable, so I shouldn't be able to use one as a key in my TreeMap.

Comment: There is no current key in the map, so inserting the first key works. And `hashCode()` isn't used to compare two Comparable objects. It has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: @JBNizet OK I just tested it. My actual code is obviously printing out info before it gets put into the TreeMap, so it looks like the treeMap is getting the data when in fact it isn't. Back to using unordered HashMaps, or subClassing TreeMap.

Comment: A TreeMap is not an ordered map. It's a sorted map. If what you want is to keep order of insertions into the map, you should use a LinkedHashMap. If you really want sorted keys, you obviously need to provide a comparator which will be used to sort your keys, since they don't have any natural order.

Comment: @JBNizet I must appologise I was getting very upset at you. My code seemed to be happily adding in TreeMap objects as keys, so I didn't believe you! So I modified my above code, ran the test... and I can o announce my code was seriously flawed somewhere down the line. I now need a better 'sorting' solution to my legacy DB data mining. I need to offer you a big thankyou, otherwise I may have been chasing this for a long time and it wouldn't have caused me problems untill later on. So back to using hashMaps for some stuff and sending the data into an SQLite / DerbyDB before playing with it!

Answer (score 6):

This is *not* a good idea.  Map keys must be immutable to work properly, and yours are not.

What are you really trying to do?  When I see people doing things like this with data structures, it makes me think that they really need an object but have forgotten that Java's an object-oriented language.

Looks like you want a crude dictionary to translate between languages.   I'd create a `LanguageLookup` class that embedded those Maps and provide some methods to make it easier for users to interact with it.  Better abstraction and encapsulation, more information hiding. Those should be your design objectives.  Think about how to add other languages besides English and French so you can use it in other contexts.

```
public class LanguageLookup { 
    private Map<String, String> dictionary;

    public LanguageLookup(Map<String, String> words) {
        this.dictionary = ((words == null) ? new HashMap<String, String>() : new HashMap<String, String>(words));
    }

    public String lookup(String from) {
        return this.dictionary.get(from);
    }

    public boolean hasWord(String word) { 
        return this.dictionary.containsKey(word);
    }
}
```

In your case, it looks like you want to translate an English word to French and then see if the French dictionary contains that word:

```
Map<String, String> englishToFrenchWords = new HashMap<String, String>();
englishToFrenchWords.put("one", "une");
Map<String, String> frenchToEnglishWords = new HashMap<String, String>();
frenchToEnglishWords.put("une", "one");
LanguageLookup englishToFrench = new LanguageLookup(englishToFrenchWords);
LanguageLookup frenchToEnglish = new LanguageLookup(frenchToEnglishWords);
String french = englishToFrench.lookup("one");
boolean hasUne = frenchToEnglish.hasWord(french);
```

Comment: I have thought about creating my own little 'keyClass' but it would have to either be a collection of them to link to a single item, or it would have to have a colection of key value pairs within it. So why re-create the wheel when java has collections that work, and then I just create my custom. I guess I could write my own TreeMap class, that inherits from treemap and then overide both hashCode() and compareTo() methods.

Comment: That's not a good enough reason to write your own TreeMap.  If I were reviewing your code, I'd make you rip that out.

Comment: @duffmo I've added in a couple of edits in the hope of clarifying my situation. I'm coming around to using another better behaved DB (derby is going to be my choice, as I intend to use if again later for something else so I can use the same communication code) to convert my original legacy one into on a temp basis.

Answer (score 2):

Your TreeMap is not Comparable so you can't add it to a SortedMap and its not immutable so you can't add it to a HashMap. What you could use an IdentityMap but suspect an EnumMap is a better choice.

```
enum Language { ENGLISH, FRENCH }

Map<Language, Map<Language, Map<String, String>>> dictionaries = 
                                                    new EnumMap<>(Language.class);

Map<Language, Map<String, String>> fromEnglishMap = new EnumMap<>(Language.class);
dictionaries.put(Language.ENGLISH, fromEnglishMap);
fromEnglishMap.put(Language.FRENCH, first);

Map<Language, Map<String, String>> fromFrenchMap = new EnumMap<>(Language.class);
dictionaries.put(Language.FRENCH, fromFrenchMap);
fromEnglishMap.put(Language.ENGLISH, second);

Map<String, String> fromEnglishToFrench= dictionaries.get(Language.ENGLISH)
                                             .get(Language.FRENCH);
```

Comment: I see what you are doing here (took a while for my brain to put it together), nice idea, unfortunately I don't know what the values of my enum are before I start, I get them programatically from a legacy DB, see my edit to my original question. So I'm not sure how I could handle the auto creation of code to build my enums etc etc etc. +1 as it sounds like an otherwise excelent solution.

Comment: You can create instances of a non-enum `Language` class instead.

Answer (score 0):

To the problem why Hashmap works and Treemap does not:

A Treemap is a "sorted map", meaning that the entries are sorted according to the key. This means that the key must be comparable, by implementing the `Comparable` interface. Maps usually do NOT implement this, and I would highly suggest you do not create a custom type to add this feature. As duffymo mentions, using maps as keys is a *BAD* idea.

Comment: I've edited my question, do you have any further comments? I've also responded to duffymo above, and said I'm going to use Derby as my temp data store, rather than maps as keys.